# postgres stats and opennms

Tags: postgresql, snmp, opennms

What is the best (or easiest?) to monitor postgres 8.4 stats in OpenNMS 1.76?

SNMP? How?

Comment: isn't that going to be using the tool to monitor part of itself, which would cause more traffic to itself?

Comment: yes, monitoring tools can generate additional traffic- but often the benefits of observability outweigh the additional traffic overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the already mentioned [pgsnmpd](http://pgsnmpd.projects.postgresql.org/) but it doesn't seem to be maintained actively (last release in August 2007). I'd rather recommend using the [check_postgres](http://bucardo.org/wiki/Check_postgres) Nagios plugin with the [NRPE plugin](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Discovery#NRPE) of OpenNMS.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that OpenNMS could read performance information via NRPE! A quick google search yields this great article: http://honglus.blogspot.com/2009/03/integrating-nagios-plugin-with-opennms.html

Answer (score 1):

A quick google on "postgresql snmp" returned the following, which should allow you to monitor the database that OpenNMS is using from itself:

- http://www.postgresql.org/about/press/features83 links to http://pgsnmpd.projects.postgresql.org/ for SNMP

Hopefully monitoring itself doesn't create a feedback loop :)